# Update column by looping through rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

I have four columns in a table `ID`, `Longitude`, `Latitude`, and `SpatialData`.  I have the first three columns filled out for every row, but I need to enter in the `SpatialData` for each row.  I can currently manually update the `SpatialData` column by using the below query:

```
update GioMap set SpatialData = 'Point(-74.009506 40.70602)' Where ID =1
```

From here I have to keep manually updating the `Longitude`, `Latitude` and `ID` for every row.  I am using this code to try to loop through all of the rows and update the table that way:

```
DECLARE @LoopC INT = 1, @MaxOID INT, 
         @Long nVarchar(32), @Lat nVarchar(32),@Col1 nVarchar(11)
 SET @MaxOID = (select count(*) from GioMap)
 Set @Col1 = 'SpatialData'

WHILE(@LoopC <= @MaxOID)
BEGIN

   SET @Long = (Select Longitude FROM GioMap where ID = @LoopC)
   SET @Lat = (Select Latitude FROM GioMap where ID = @LoopC)

   DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('update GioMap set ' + @Col1 +' = ' + '''' + 'Point(' + @Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')' + '''' + ' Where ID = ' + @LoopC) 

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

  SET @LoopC  = @LoopC + 1        
END
```

When I run this code I keep getting this error message:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'update [ISSHXI1].[dbo].[GioMap] set SpatialDat = 'Point(-74.0095 40.706)' Where ID = ' to data type int.
```

I don't understand why it would be trying to convert it to an int?

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop? And why dynamic sql?

Comment: This is the only way I could think to do it.  Is there another way?  Also, the reason it's dynamic is because this will need to be used over and over again on other tables that may have different column names.

Comment: the @loop needs to be converted in your declare where your update is

Comment: @manderson what would I convert it too?  Doesn't it need to be an int so that I can iterate through it?  If it's a string I won't be able to keep adding 1 to it correct?

Comment: Please add the statement print @ sql right before the sp_execute statement. Your @sql may not contain what you think it does.

Comment: See the answer below from Giorgos. However, the reason your code was failing is because you are missing a comma between your two parameters to the Point function. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE GioMap SET SpatialData = 'Point(' + cast(Longitude as varchar) + ' ' + cast(Latitude as varchar) + ')'
```

Comment: Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was just about to type this very query. If you are missing something, I am too.

Comment: I was about to post this...however, you need to add a comma between Longitude and Latitude.

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. He is actually trying to do this.

Comment: @SeanLange are you sure? I don't see a comma in the original example...

Comment: So that will work for all the rows??? I was using this website [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2552/creating-an-ssrs-map-report-with-data-pinpoints/) to figure out how to do it and it said you had to do all the lines individually.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I am pretty sure that was one of the problems the OP was dealing with.

Comment: @VBA_SQL_Programmer give it a try and let us know, there are many people around to help!

Comment: My problem was that I just didn't know you could do this for the whole column.  I thought SQL had to go row by row.  Sorry for wasting your guys time, but I really appreciate the help.  The code you put worked perfectly.

Comment: No worries, we had a nice chat as well [contrary to the strict SO rules :-)] Take care!

Comment: And since you understand a better way of doing this no time was wasted by anybody. Glad you learned a new technique today.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are doing it is bad, but that's not technically what you asked.

It is trying to convert it to an int because you are adding a varchar to an int.  You need to change this:

> DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('update GioMap set ' + @Col1 +' = ' +
>   '''' + 'Point(' + @Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')' + '''' + ' Where ID = ' +
>   @LoopC)

to this

> DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('update GioMap set ' + @Col1 +' = ' +
>   '''' + 'Point(' + @Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')' + '''' + ' Where ID = ' +
>   **Cast(@LoopC as varchar))**

Answer (score 0):

The point statement paramaters need to be seperated by a comma.
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('update GioMap set ' + @Col1 +' = ' + '''' + 'Point(' + @Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')' + '''' + ' Where ID = ' + @LoopC)

Instead of:

```
@Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')
     try 
@Long + ',' + @Lat + ')
```

To see what is being executed you can try adding a print statement:

```
 DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('update GioMap set ' + @Col1 +' = ' + '''' + 'Point(' + @Long + ' ' + @Lat + ')' + '''' + ' Where ID = ' + @LoopC) 
 print @sql
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Also why do you parans around strings you are assigning? Its confusing   in TSQL. While it works it is jarring and unusual.
Instead of:

```
SET @MaxOID =  (select count(*) from GioMap)
   try
SET @MaxOID =  'select count(*) from GioMap'
```

Later in the code you do both parens and quotes. The great, great majority of TSQL developers just use single quotes.

Ben